# SciComp migration option?

Tags: feature-request, migration

There have been a number of posts recently that I wanted to mark for migration to the scicomp.SE site (e.g., [this recent one on RK4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88854/)), but the only options for migration are this meta site and the math.SE site.

I usually just leave a comment suggesting the OP ask on the scicomp site, but should there be a migration option for scicomp?

Comment: Don't you get a third option: "**belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network** type to search" in the pop-up window Closing>Off-Topic>Migration, when you vote to close it?

Comment: I do not get that :(

Comment: @Qmechanic That is a mod-only feature

Comment: @MadScientist: Oh, I see. Also I was thinking of the close button, while Kyle Kanos probably was thinking of the flag button Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic>Migration, since he doesn't have 3k rep yet.

Comment: @Qmechanic 3k non-mods can vote Closing > Off-Topic > Migration, but the only options are to Meta.Physics or to Math. There is no search or custom field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Computational Science is a beta site, so I don't think it makes sense to have that migration option yet. We want to be really careful about migrating to beta sites because the questions there could potentially be lost at any point. That being said, if you think a question is off topic here *and* seems like it should go to scicomp.SE, flag it for moderator attention with a suggestion that it be migrated. For 3k-ers, I don't know if the system will let you vote to close as off topic as well, but if it does, you should do that too, in addition to casting a custom flag.

Whenever scicomp.SE graduates, we can reconsider this proposal.

Comment: I disagree; scicomp already survived 2 years and its only problem is a number of questions asked daily. The chance of closing is practically zero.

Comment: I'd call for expressing our interest now and letting the team decide when SciComp is ready to be on official migration target.

Comment: Well, the fact that scicomp hasn't graduated yet indicates that the team doesn't consider it stable, and that's what really counts. Of course personally I don't think it's in danger of failing.

Comment: Well, there may be a period when they have decided to graduate the site, but Jin and his crew haven't gotten a nice theme together or something. But yeah, I think that graduation is the main sign that the team is satisfied about the long-term prospects of a site.

Comment: @mbq As a matter of SE policy, beta sites don't get incoming migration paths since they're supposed to grow organically. (There used to be one from [english.se] to [writers.se], but it's gone now) Though I agree that an old beta site really doesn't need all those restrictions if most of its aspects are up to par with a graduated site.

Comment: I just feel the graduation is now much more a matter of waiting on the pile than an effect of actual assessment; especially when a site is avid but niche. And that we can help scicomp with questions and traffic rather than disturb it.

Comment: @mbq Not exactly, as IIRC SciComp is not even in the graduation queue. But I do have a proposal in mind that may improve this which I plan to post on MSO, but it will involve radical changes.

Comment: @mbq Just FYI, [Answers.OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/) has [very good stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) (better than SciComp) and has been around for over 3 years, but [is going to be closed](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/1062/answers-onstartups-will-close-on-november-12-2013). I highly doubt SciComp will have the same fate, but the stats alone don't disprove it.

Comment: @Manishearth I trust you'll post a link here if you do ;) - not all of us visit MSO daily.